# Number Format Exception JSP Page with cookies

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

I wrote this small code for handling cookies.However,when i click on the "next" button it throws a 
**java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "current"**

Code:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
int current=0;
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
Cookie cookie = null;
if(cookies != null){
    for(int i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){
        if(cookies[i].getName().equals("last"))
            cookie = cookies[i];    
        }
}

if(cookie != null){
    String btn = request.getParameter("button");
            if(btn != null){
                if(btn.equals("next"))
                    current = Integer.parseInt(cookie.getValue()) + 1;
                else
                    current = Integer.parseInt(cookie.getValue()) - 1;
            }
}
response.addCookie(new Cookie("last",String.valueOf("current")));
out.println(current);
%>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
   <form method="post">    
       <input type="submit" name="button" value="prev" />
       <input type="submit" name="button" value="next" />
     </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the cookie to value `"current"`

```
String.valueOf("current")
```

but you want

```
String.valueOf(current)
```